# run CTS on specific device using its usb id

Tags: android, usb, adb, cts

I'm working on script which suppose run CTS Tests on multiple devices.
unfortunately, while i check the serial number of my android devices I see that part of them contains identical serial number.
now, I read about an option to run `adb devices -l` to get usb entering of my devices, in order to I could run command on specific usb:

```
$ adb devices -l

List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF device usb:2-1.8 
0123456789ABCDEF device usb:2-1.7
```

now, we can run this command on specific usb instead specific serial number as before:

```
$ adb -s usb:26200000 install xxx.apk
```

I want to do similar thing while I run CTS on specific android device:

```
$ ./cts-tradefed run cts -s usb:2-1.8 -p android.permission2
```

The problem is that it looks like the command not working. there isn't any response when I try this.

please, anybody can tell me if there is another way to run cts on specific device while there are two identical serial numbers?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of forcing `adb` to use a specific device besides `-s` parameter. You can assign your device id to the `ANDROID_SERIAL` environment variable. That works great for 3rd party scripts which do not support specifying the required id otherwise.

Comment: thank you, but i have still problem. my script suppose to run the cts tests in parrallel. i can't set ANDROID_SERIAL environment variable for each device. i'm looking for something with usb entering for the cts tests

Answer (score 0):

You can select between multiple devices you use the command `list devices` to get the serial of the devices:

```
l d
```

Example

```
cts-tf > l d
Serial               State   Allocation  Product      Variant      Build            Battery  
10.1.1.113:5555      ONLINE  Allocated   product      variant      2018.02.2       100
```

and then run cts with `--serial` parameter

```
run cts --serial <id>
```

where `<id>` is the first column in the result from `l d` command

Even if the parameter's name is `serial` in fact the value you give to it is the `device id`(as given by the command `l d` or `list devices`) and not the actual serial of the device.

Comment: it doesn't help.. in case of duplicate serial number, I have no way no distinguish between them. i don't reallize, is   **10.1.1.113:5555** serial number include the usb entring?

Comment: @dvir In my test-case it was a tcp connection over Ethernet but the principle is the same, can you please do the `l d` command and post what this command lists?

Comment: @dvir also even if the argument is serial in fact you give the `device id`  as parameter and not the actual serial of the device and those should not be identical as you can see when you give the `l d` command

Comment: but the problem is when i type    **l d**   command, the output is idetical to the serial device of the android. it's seems differnet of your output. if i have 2 identical devices which connect parrallel, then i haven't anything which give me the ability to distinguish between them

Comment: I cannot guess what you are looking at, can you please post the exact output